# Vue project is deployed to tomcat, unable to send Ajax request to display 404

Tags: vue.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFXcQ.png)The Vue project works well in vscode, but deployed to tomcat, can't send an Ajax request, showing 404

[image]

[image]

Comment: Vue JS sent Ajax request as expected. Where are your REST ep is located?

Comment: What does REST EP mean? Ajax did send requests, but the same code running in vscode sent Ajax requests and fetched data, but the same code that I deployed to Tomcat sent requests that could not fetch data. Is it because the cross domain and later in a domain do not get the request? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The request was successful in vscode, but failed in Tomcat.

Comment: from your requests, your ajax code is trying to communicate to a API (REST End Point). Which is not available. Check the server and context path.